# display only one error message in contactForm

Tags: php

I have very limited knowlege about php, but need to diplay only one error message if the user does not fill all of the fields in this contact form. The way it is now is that is it diplays the smame message multiple times on diffetent lines.

[image]

```
$errormessage =  '<p class="error">Please fill out all fields correctly</p>';


    // A bunch of if's for all the fields and the error messages.
if ( empty($_REQUEST['name']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $errormessage;
} elseif ( ereg( "[][{}()*+?.\\^$|]", $_REQUEST['name'] ) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $errormessage;
}
if ( empty($_REQUEST['email']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $errormessage;
} elseif ( !eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$", $_REQUEST['email']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $errormessage;
}
if ( empty($_REQUEST['message']) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $errormessage;
} elseif ( ereg( "[][{}()*+?\\^$|]", $_REQUEST['message'] ) ) {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .= $errormessage;
}
```

Comment: `.=` operator made the variable could be filled by multiple values

Comment: so your `$alert` will have two or more error message if the error is more than one

Comment: Thank you Oki Erie Rinaldi, like i mentioned I have a very limited knowlege about php. Could you clarify a little bit please.

Comment: may be you have to replace `.=` with `=`.

Comment: but note that `=` will replace the previous value of the same variable

Comment: Do you want the error message shown specifically or just showing the error message if one or more of the required field is error?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript, on click submit button call javascript function..
**Try This:-**

> javascript

```
<script>
function validation()
{
    $name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if ( $name == "") 
    {
        alert("Error");
        return false;
    } 
}
</script>
```

> HTML

```
<form id="frmReg" name="frmReg" action="" onsubmit="return validation();"></form>
```

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi: Use return keyword in front of function call

Comment: Ya, I don't matter with it :D